# Documents 'Send To' another site collection permission issue

Tags: 2013, permissions

Is it possible to send a document to another site collection (that's not a Records Centre), even if the user doesn't have permission to that site?

My client wants users to be able to send documents to another site collection without having permissions to that site. When a user does send a document via 'Send To' they get the message 'Let us know why you need access to this site' & 'Awaiting approval' - they don't need access!

I have checked and the document delivers to the correct location.

Answer (score 1):

To send a document through the 'Send To>Other Location' function, you need to have write access to the destination document library. If the document is going to the destination library without proper access, check if that user has any admin level accounts (farm/site collection) on the destination site.